# How to map object values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to map `Date` values by extracting the values from object. Following is the code for reference:

```
const [newDate, setNewDate] = useState([]);

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);

    return dat;
};

const getDates = (startDate, stopDate) => {
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var currentDate = startDate;

    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    }

    return dateArray
}

const dateArray2 = getDates(new Date(), new Date().addDays(30));

useEffect(() => {
    setNewDate(dateArray2)
}, [])

return (
    <>
        {console.log('Date', newDate)}
    </>
)
```

Here I get the data but I am unable to map it properly. Mapping in this manner gives the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Mar 12 2021 17:23:28 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
newDate.map((data) => (
    <h3>{data}</h3>
))
```

What could be the best possible solution?

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nxhwg

Comment: No its giving error as 'Object are valid as react child'

Comment: Please refer codesandbox link

Comment: Your code is a total mess. Ignoring that, you're getting the error because you're trying to render a date object by using `<h3>{data}</h3>`. You should stringify the date first: `<h3>{data.toString()}</h3>`. Also, all of this is explained in the error you receive.

Comment: [It's best to avoid modifying objects you don't own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1218980) (`Date` here).

Comment: @zhulien OK I will try this solution

Comment: @jperl OK I will be careful